# Anychart barchart: simultanously add label on top and both at the bottom of a bar

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

In Anychart, how can we make a barchart with both a label on top of the bar, and also at the bottom of the bar? See the sketch below.

[barchart sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weOs8.png)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you can use this sample with two scales: https://playground.anychart.com/dhxgOXbR

Also, please check these two samples, easier to implement:
https://playground.anychart.com/x5x80IHa
https://playground.anychart.com/Idv6MQH3

To enable labels in a bar chart write this line: chart.labels(true) or series.labels(true) - for the series.